# Extracting binary data with Exiftool

Tags: image, binary-data, steganography, exiftool

I am doing a steganography challenge. I have a jpeg file, and when I look the metadata of it with Exiftool, I see something interesting.

```
Red Tone Reproduction Curve     : (Binary data 64 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Green Tone Reproduction Curve   : (Binary data 64 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Blue Tone Reproduction Curve    : (Binary data 64 bytes, use -b option to extract)
```

So I thought that maybe there is something interesting there, but I am not sure on how to extract that binary data. When I use the following command: `exiftool -b -RedTRC nameOfThePicture.jpeg`, then I get this message: `curv          ck?Q!)2;FQw]kpz|i}0`.
I think that message can be something but I don't how to extract that binary data and which type of file could it be. Any help?

Comment: [Related post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=11406.msg61081#msg61081) on the exiftool forums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That "message" is simply the binary data of that tag displayed on the command line.  The `curv` part is the ID value for the TRC (see [example code](http://www.color.org/icc-book1.pdf#page=60), specifically `tagbase.sig = swap((long)0x63757276L); /*’curv’*/`).

To extract that data to a file, you just need to redirect the output.
`exiftool -b -RedTRC nameOfThePicture.jpeg >RedTRC.dat`

Comment: So, I suppose that is not something interesting. Thank you ;) @StarGeek